# How we calculate the Depth of Convolution Output?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network, convolution

**How we get Feature maps number in the Conv output (Depth H)**

I think that **H** = **D** * **number of filters** !!

[image]

[source of picture](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1N7uSKlnQ_8msi-kv3cPoOuZPjUZiyXH3)

Comment: By my reading of the figure, H __is__ the number of filters. Can you post the source of this figure or some of the surrounding text?

Comment: @myrtlecat this is the source : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1N7uSKlnQ_8msi-kv3cPoOuZPjUZiyXH3

Comment: based on the source document I will stick with my answer: H can be chosen freely and does not depend on D, N or k. I'll update my answer below with the relevant quote from the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

H can be chosen freely. It does not depend on any of the other parameters.

Each of the H "feature maps" will be produced by a different k x k x D kernel. This is often described as a single 4D kernel with shape H x k x k x D.

In the source text it says the same thing, but perhaps more clearly:

> The input is of size N x N x D and is convolved with H kernels, each of size k x k x D separately. Convolution of an input with one kernel produces one output feature, and with H kernels independently produces H features.

The terminology can be confusing at first, as there are multiple terms used for the same thing. H could be called the *number of kernels*, or *number of filters*, or *number of output features* or the *number of filter maps*.

Comment: thank you, Mr @myrtlecat 
so he can't be described by any of D or K or D

Comment: See also: [Analysis and Optimization of Convolutional Neural Network Architectures](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.09725.pdf), Chapter 2 (begining from page 3). Especially figure 2.2